# I want to help my dog feel better

Tags: dogs

One day I accidentally hurt my cute little dog and she got so scared she thought she had to stay by me 24/7. She had her head down looking scared, literally.

Than after a while she was always close to me and I didn't notice and accidentally kicked he. She cried a little and she stayed by me even more then. It keeps on going and going. I want my dog to know that she can be a farther distance away from me and we can be buds again and snuggle without crying.

I don't know how to help this. How do I?